# How can I format my "Date.Today" to go from MM/dd/yyyy to dd/MM/yyyy in VB.Net?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, date, datetime

Basically I am having a problem fixing my "Date" and how it saves in SQL. It works now, it inserts into the table etc but not in the format I actually want it to insert like. It inserts as `MM/dd/yyyy` (the American Way as far as I know) but I need to be placed in the format that we use here in the UK, so yes it needs to display as `dd/MM/yyyy` (03/05/2014).

Is it actually possible to convert it for my different time zone & if so, how is it done? (And by done I mean guide me otherwise I won't learn.)

Here is my code on how it stands as of including my insert into the actual SQL Database.

```vb
 Protected Sub OkBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles OkBtn.Click
    Try
        '  Dim DayNo As Integer = 0
        ' Dim DateNo As Integer = 0
        ' Dim StartingDay As Integer = 0
        Dim ThisDay As Date = Date.Today
            ' Dim Week As Integer = 1
            ' StartingDay = ThisDay.AddDays(-(ThisDay.Day - 1)).DayOfWeek
            ' DayNo = ThisDay.DayOfWeek
            ' DateNo = ThisDay.Day
            ' Week = Fix(DateNo / 7)
            ' If DateNo Mod 7 > 0 Then
            'Week += 1
            ' End If
            ' If StartingDay > DayNo Then
            'Week += 1
            ' End If
            'Dim ThisWeek As String
            ' ThisWeek = Week
            Dim ThisUser As String
            ThisUser = Request.QueryString("")
            If ThisUser = "" Then
                ThisUser = "Chris Heywood"
            End If
            connection.Open()
            command = New SqlCommand("Insert Into FireTest([Date],[Type],[Comments],[Completed By]) Values(@Date,@Type,@Comments,@CompletedBy)", connection)
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", ThisDay.ToString)
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Type", DropDownList1.SelectedValue)
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Comments", TextBox2.Text)
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompletedBy", ThisUser)
            'command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Week", ThisWeek)
            command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Please make sure all fields are filled in!")
    End Try
    connection.Close()
    Response.Redirect("~/Production/Navigator.aspx")
End Sub
```

EDIT: I have edited the way it inserts & that works but still , it doesn't appear as dd/MM/yyyy.

Comment: Don't store dates as strings! Change the type of your column to `date` (or `datetime` for older versions of SQL), and do your formatting in the client.

Comment: When using `AddWithValue` the type of the added value should reflect the column type in DB. So in your case your sql column named [Date] is a "string" column?

Comment: Richard , in SQL it is a Date type , is this where I would be going wrong as I am trying to save it as a string?

Comment: Any rdbms can store a `datetime`, so why do you use a string? Also, a `MessageBox` on a server doesn't make much sense. You should also use the `using`-statement  for the connection to ensure that it get's closed as soon as possible, even on error.

Comment: @Kallumasaurus: Yes, if the SQL type is `date`, then you need to pass it as a date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your database column is a `date` type, remove the `.ToString` call when adding the parameter:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", ThisDay)
```

Answer (score 2):

don't save date time as string in your database,  if you have date time data type in Date column

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", ThisDay)
```

you don't need to call `tostring`

but in this case i would not even use parameter. i will let db to insert the date

```
Insert Into FireTest([Date],[Type],[Comments],[Completed By]) Values(GETDATE(),@Type,@Comments,@CompletedBy)
```

Answer (score 1):

It may be possible to try `Date.Today.ToShortDateString` .

The other method that i use it `Date.Today.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")`

Try them and then get back to me.

EDIT:

Try this :

```
Dim culture As New CultureInfo("fr-FR") 
Date.Today.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", culture)
```

Comment: I have tried both of them methods none of which work as it can't convert Date to string.

Answer (score 1):

When using `AddWithValue` the type of the added value should reflect the column type in DB. Just change your code to this:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", Date.Today)
```